# 12 V relay using Arduino

Tags: arduino-nano, relay, transistor

I want to control a 12 V relay using an Arduino 5 V signal, but due to some unknown reason the relay does not work. I am using a BC548 transistor as a switch for relay.[image]
Please suggest where I go wrong.

Comment: issue aside, you need a flyback diode to save your NPN. Does the relay trigger if you feed the NPN +5v instead of a GPIO output?

Comment: I have added flyback diode in actual circuit forget to add in diagram.

Comment: yes the relay works when I give 12v to base

Comment: what about 5v, like the AVR would provide?

Comment: i didn't tried it but It only works when i give higher than 5v

Comment: It could be a lot of things then. I would swap the NPN for an NCHAN mosfet, preferably logic-level. I use the IRLZ44N in a lot of 3.3v projects, makes a great low-side switch.

Comment: Have you connected the grounds?

Comment: @Majenko yes i did.

Answer (score 3):

If it's working with 12v on the input but not 5v, it sounds like the base resistor value 
 (which is missing from the diagram) might be too high. A value of around 1k should ensure the transistor is fully switched on.